# Lectura de archivos con Arreglos Dinámicos Bidimensionales

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tengo un problema, segun a lo que yo tengo conocimiento mi código debería de correr pero no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal en mi código que me reconoce los registros pero no me los guarda de forma correcta en mi arreglo dinámico y mucho menos lo muestra.

**Clase principal**

```
public class Ejercicio_10 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List < List < String >> dat = new ArrayList < > ();
  int c = 0;
  Lectura in = new Lectura();
  c = in .lee("C:\\Users\\ASASCED\\Music\\México.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
   dat.add(new ArrayList < String > ());
  }
  String[][] arr = new String[c][5]; in .asigna(dat, "C:\\Users\\ASASCED\\Music\\México.txt");
  for (int y = 0; y < c; y++) {
   System.out.println("Registro " + y);
   System.out.println("C.P. " + dat.get(0).get(y));
   System.out.println(dat.get(1).get(y));
   System.out.println(dat.get(2).get(y));
   System.out.println(dat.get(3).get(y));
   System.out.println(dat.get(4).get(y));
   System.out.println("");
  }
 }
}
```

**Clase Lectura**

```
public class Lectura {

    File archivo = null;
    FileReader ciudadmexico = null;
    BufferedReader reg = null;
    String registro = "";
    int c = 0;

    public int lee(String fileread) {
        try {
            archivo = new File(fileread);
            ciudadmexico = new FileReader(archivo);
            reg = new BufferedReader(ciudadmexico);

            while ((reg.readLine()) != null) {
                c = c + 1;
                // System.out.println("Registro "+c+" es "+registro+"ame");
                // reg.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No leyó, quizás no encontró el archivo");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != ciudadmexico) {
                    System.out.println(fileread + " Total de registros leídos: " + c);
                    ciudadmexico.close();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error en total de registros");
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void asigna(List<List<String>> x, String fileread) {
        int nr = 0;

        Campos invo = new Campos();
        try {
            archivo = new File(fileread);
            ciudadmexico = new FileReader(archivo);
            reg = new BufferedReader(ciudadmexico);

            while ((registro = reg.readLine()) != null) {
                invo.descompone(registro, x, nr);
                nr++;
                // reg.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al reconocer el archivo...");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != ciudadmexico) {
                    ciudadmexico.close();
                    // Captura inn = new Captura();
                    // inn.datos(arreg,c);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar el archivo en descompone...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Campos**

```
public class Campos {

 public void descompone(String regis, List < List < String >> x, int nreg) {
  // String[] signifi={"C.P.","Colonia","Municipio","Ciudad","Estado"};
  String separador = "|";
  String a = "";
  int pos = 0, i = 0;

  while (regis.indexOf(separador) > -1) {
   a = regis.substring(0, regis.indexOf(separador));
   x.get(nreg).set(i, a);
   //arre[nreg][i] = a;
   // System.out.print(a+" ");
   pos = regis.indexOf(separador) + separador.length();
   regis = regis.substring(pos, regis.length());
   i++;
  }
  // System.out.println("");
  x.get(nreg).set(i, regis);
  //arre[nreg][i] = regis;
 }
}
```

Enlace del archivo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vB5PSaxeNjDuwBPPLkUdob1isd73e7qG

Comment: Es que declaras el array pero no lo usas.

Comment: Gracias no me di cuenta de eso, si que hice una pregunta tonta :(